# Getting an error when trying to insert data to table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this code in a php file:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tec (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$done=mysql_query($query);
if($done == 'null') {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'message' => $mess['error'].$done.'</b></div>'));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'message' => $mess['success']));
}
```

It inserts a name into a table named "tec". If `$done == 'null'` then I print an error message.
The problem is that when I run the code, it inserts the data correctly, but I get the error message.
I tried to read `$done` and its equal to 1.
Should I do something like:

```
if($done == 1){
    //OK
}else{
    //NOT OK
}
```

Or is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says that `mysql_query` returns `FALSE` on error. That means instead of testing whether it's equal to `'null'` (a string which compares as `TRUE`), you could just test the boolean-ness directly:

```
if($done){
    //OK
}else{
    //NOT OK
}
```

I would be remiss if I didn't mention that the `mysql_*` family of functions is *deprecated*, **unsafe**, and ***will be removed*** from future versions of PHP! Instead, I can personally recommend [PDO](https://www.sitepoint.com/re-introducing-pdo-the-right-way-to-access-databases-in-php/), which I've used with a good amount of success.

Comment: @Juanky Awesome! Could you please accept my answer? Then I could get that strangely addicting point bonus.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation of mysql_query function's php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

So, search if it's TRUE or FALSE.

```
if ($done == TRUE) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi  I think you should use boolean 
just try this   (you'd better use mysqli instead mysql

```
if(!done) 
{
// something wrong
 echo mysql.. 
}
else 
{
// everything works fine....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error catching must be like the following:

```
if($done === false){
    //NOT OK
}else{
    //OK
}
```

But as @John Conde mentioned do not use mysql_* because its deprecated.